# Test out new kernel with full ability of rollback

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04, with kernel 3.19.0-43-generic, and have been using Backports for getting appropriate Wi-Fi drivers (see the following thread: https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/pull/2).

The Wi-Fi is however not working very reliably, and I often have to reload the module using modprobe for it to work. Inspired by a post in the thread I linked to, I would like to try out the 4.3 kernel or later, for getting my Wi-Fi working without Backports.

My concern is that I also need my Nvidia GTX 980M card to be working properly. I have got it working using a 3rd party PPA.

I am up for testing out both newer kernels and newer Ubuntu versions, but what I wonder is whether such an upgrade could break my current system (concern is GPU drivers) - or if it is possible to rollback the upgrade as if nothing had happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always remove the new kernel, even if your system is  "broken" in a sense that the Nvidia module does not build OK.

Enter the console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and remove the kernel by running a `sudo dpkg -r <package_name>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have now installed the 4.3.0 kernel and both Wi-Fi and graphics drivers are working!

For a moment I was not that confident though, as the computer couldn't find the GPU at all. That was however simply due to me accidently switching off the (external) GPU of my MSI GT72 2QE Dominator Pro laptop with a hardware button, causing it to use the integrated graphics card.